# Smooth Scroll is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have copied `javascript` code of smooth scroll from stackoverflow and modified in my page but it is not working.

The Original Code is given here:

http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/dN4S4/1/

The Modified Code :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYmLva

Comment: what specifically isn't working about it?

Comment: smooth scrolling is not working. when i click on a link it displayed on the header it directly takes me to that div. i have check using console.log() but no event are passes in jQuery

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues:

1. `JQuery` was not linked in your codepen
2. Your `id`s in your `a` tags looked like this:

   ```
   id="#sld1" //should be just sld1 no #
   ```

instead of this

```
    id="sld1" // # isn't included in HTML, thats a CSS indicator
```

3. you were calling:

   ```
   onmousedown="autoScroll('slide1');
   ```

In your `a` tags but `autoSCroll` was not defined in your JS

4. This line in your `if` statment:

   ```
   $(this).get(0).id
   ```

Should just be `$(this).attr("id")`

5. `overflow: hidden` on your `body, html` was preventing the page from animate scrolling down. Remove that.

In fact you don't need those `if` statements at all. Since you're calling the `id` of the `div` in your `href` you can simply do:

```
 target = $(this).attr("href");
```

Which would return: `#slide1` or `#slide2`, etc. That will target your `div` of the same `id`

[**NEW CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEVPBe)

Comment: 1st Error : i am working also on my offline browser and there i used jquery library....... 2nd Error : thanks for it.... 3rd Error : i was trying to make own experiment and forget to remove that in the actual code........ 4th Error : i used the given statement by you........... 5th Error : if i make my html overflow:hidden then my parallax is not working.... after all this yet my smooth scrolling is not working